# Why evenlistener not working properly at jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, addeventlistener

Please have a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/franenos/rff9vcpx/)
or here:

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function myFunction() {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box");
}, false);
```

why this evenlistener not working? It should work because it works everywhere else. I think it's because of the iframe but I dunno...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured JS Fiddle to wrap your code in an onload event handler.

The sequence of events is:

1. Load event handler is bound.
2. DOM Content Loaded fires. There is nothing listening for it.
3. Load event fires.
4. Load handler executes and binds the DOM Content Loaded listener

[image: JS Fiddle Screenshot]

You need to bind the event handler before the event it is listening for fires. Change the JS Fiddle options to one of the "no wrap" choices. Since you aren't touching anything in the DOM, it doesn't matter which of the two you select.

Answer (score 1):

Change `load type` to `No wrap - in body`

To change `Load Type`, click on label `JAVASCRIP` in script section, a pop will appears.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rff9vcpx/7/).

This might be because, by default, your script's load type in `On Load`, so all your script is loaded but your DOM is yet to render.

Comment: Thanks. Can't say why, but it wasn't updated(perhaps because I'm the one who started the jsfiddle?), anywhat I updated it so anyone will see for more info.

Comment: Oops! shared incorrect fiddle reference. I have updated my answer.