# Bulma navigation responsiveness is off

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bulma

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ycLumo3k/

I am using the exact same code I see in [Bulma documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/)

But, as you see, the hamburger menu is not working as expected.

I'm wondering what the difference is between my code and the original code?

Could someone take a look and help me figure it out?

For convenience, I put the code snippet here too:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
          </a>

          <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start">
            <a class="navbar-item">
              Home
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item">
              Documentation
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a class="navbar-link">
                More
              </a>

              <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  About
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Jobs
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Contact
                </a>
                <hr class="navbar-divider">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Report an issue
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary">
                  <strong>Sign up</strong>
                </a>
                <a class="button is-light">
                  Log in
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down the Bulma doc page, it says:

> The Bulma package **does not come with any JavaScript**. You will need to implement the necessary javascript yourself.

Here is some example code which gives the necessary navbar functionality:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any navbar burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach( el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        const target = el.dataset.target;
        const $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time on it. But, it didn't work.

Comment: @Mojtaba See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130982/why-evenlistener-not-working-properly-at-jsfiddle

Comment: the JavaScript code you provided did not work. But, I was able to manage to get it working. To be fair, I think the credit of the answer should go to you. But, to help the other developers who might see this post later, could you update your answer with the working code I added?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @oshah81 for pointing to need to JavaScript.

However, the piece of code was a bit different.

For those who might be interested in, you can find the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/r5bhdkLe/

```js
(function() {
  var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  var nav = document.querySelector('#'+burger.dataset.target);
 
  burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
          </a>

          <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start">
            <a class="navbar-item">
              Home
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item">
              Documentation
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a class="navbar-link">
                More
              </a>

              <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  About
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Jobs
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Contact
                </a>
                <hr class="navbar-divider">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Report an issue
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary">
                  <strong>Sign up</strong>
                </a>
                <a class="button is-light">
                  Log in
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```